# Place A view in front of multiple views

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place an image view in front of two different view Help me to create this image is shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the layout I have created that you want.

This is the layout file and you also need one drawable for making the border of the imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="This is bottom layout."
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ll_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_image_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Drawable file**

create new drawable named **drawable_image_border**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="50dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: real problem is to place map in empty space

Comment: yes, then you can add supportedMapFragment there in a main relative layout.